# How can I improve sort function here?

Tags: c, linked-list

Hi I am trying to implement sort function.
With this function, my expected output should be increasing order.
For example, if there is three names such as jarvan, anivia, ziggs, then the output should be organized like anivia, jarvan, ziggs.
But this gives me the issue that process is stuck at a while loop.
Without sort function, this code works very well. but with it, it dosen't.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct linkedList{
    char name[30];
    char surname[30];
    int grade;
    struct linkedList *next;
} Node;

void swap(char *p, char *q)
{
    char temp;
    temp=*p;
    *p=*q;
    *q=temp;
}

void sort(Node *head)
{
    Node *p=head, *q;
    while(1)
    {
        if (q->surname > p->surname)
        {
            swap(*q->surname,*p->surname);
        }
        if (q->next ==NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
        q=q->next;
        if (p->next ==NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
        p=p->next;
    }
}



Node *readList(Node *head)
{
    FILE *dataFile;
    dataFile = fopen("12.txt", "r");
    if(dataFile == NULL) {
        printf("no file\n");
    } else {
        printf("students\n");
    }
    while (!feof (dataFile))
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
            fscanf(dataFile, "%s %s %d", &head -> name, &head -> surname, &head -> grade);
            head -> next = NULL;
        } else {
            Node *current = head;
            Node *temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
            while(current -> next != NULL) {
                current = current -> next;
            }
            fscanf(dataFile, "%s %s %d", &temp -> name, &temp -> surname, &temp -> grade);
            current -> next = temp;
            temp -> next = NULL;
        }
    return head;
}

void printList(Node *head)
{
    Node *current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%s %s %d\n", current -> name, current -> surname, current -> grade);
        current = current -> next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
    return;
}
int main()
{
    Node* AB=NULL;
    AB=readList(AB);
    sort(AB);
    printList(AB);   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `q->surname > p->surname` looks strange. String comparisions should be via `strcmp()`.

Comment: [`while (!feof (dataFile))` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). You should check return values of `fscanf()` to check if readings are successful.

Comment: `q` is used without being initialized. This must be the cause of "stuck at a while loop".

Comment: @MikeCAT hm.. so maybe like this? ```res= strcmp(p, q);
  if (res > 0)
  {
   swap(*q->surname,*p->surname);
  }```

Comment: Style guide: the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly
because they are [postfix operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3).
They should not be written with spaces around them.
Writing `current -> surname` is not idiomatic C and indicates that the coder
is a tyro (newbie).  Use `current->surname`.

Comment: Hmmm, both of implementation and usage of `swap` is wrong. At least `swap` requires pointers as arguments, so pointers should be passed instead of dereferened `char`. Also, your `swap` will swap only the first characters of the strings. `strcpy()` is useful to copy strings.

Comment: `char*` should be passed to `strcmp()`, not `Node*`.

Comment: By "improve" sort, did you mean other sort algorithms? Merge sort for linked lists would be faster, but normally it's fastest to copy linked list to an array, sort the array, create a new sorted linked list. This is what Java collections.sort() does.